# Meaning of と言うやつ

Tags: translation

> これがネグレクトと言うやつだろうか

This is from here. https://bokete.jp/boke/69302929

Is the やつ here still derogatory or "guy"?

Does this mean anything close to "Guy who says this is neglect." But that sorta sounds wrong to me when I think of だろうか to add to it. I'm not that good yet but it sounds kinda rude to me. So I thought that I was missing something in that translation I gave.